Up-to-date books on Automotive PCI Express or PCIe in general at least?
I am seeking for an up-to-date book about Automotive PCI Express, or at least about PCI Express in general.
For Automotive Ethernet, a competing technology of in-vehicle communications, there are at least two up-to-date books, Automotive Ethernet (recent edition 2021) and Automotive High Speed Communication Technologies (new as 2022).
Could you recommend me such a fresh book on Automotive PCIe or PCIe in general, dated from 2020 to today?

See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. This might be considered a shopping / resource hunting question and liable for closure.

@Transistor How should I reformulate the question if I really search for such the knowledge?

Best bet is to get the PCIe standard from the PCI SIG.
In my opinion...
Use of PCIe in automotive is likely to be limited to use on the ECU PCB vs. any sort of cable connection. Automotive has different requirements for environmental (temperature, vibration, etc.), quality, and safety than you will find in more typical computer related industries (PC, networking, etc.).
Information in books regarding standards always lag the standard. So if you are looking for new/emerging information a book your search is going to come up short. The other issue with books is that they try to restate the standard and invariably introduce unintended errors and confusion.
Best to rely on the standard itself.

I disagree. At least since 2021 there were many talks and presentations on short and long reach PCIe applications within a car. Just google "Automotive PCI Express". But I see no general-purpose books on this.

Well... it will be interesting how PCIe addresses the security requirements necessary to unlock safety related applications.

As I can see from the same talks and presentations, the functional safety (called FuSa in those docs) is an integral part of Automotive PCIe.

I am familiar with all existing PCI Express Base Specification revisions, up to 6.0 with FLIT and PAM-4, but I need for something more general and conceptual instead of strict technical. I searched Amazon and tried also googling, but the recent that I found is about PCIe 3.0 dated back to far before 2020. In my quested (now banned as I can understand) I mentioned the example of up-to-date books on a competing technology. I am still very surprised about nothing such of PCIe.

Nothing and noone has been banned. The question is simply not according to the rules and requirements of EE SE, the reason given in the closure note above the question. If you're able to reformulate your question such that it is relevant, it will promptly be opened again.
